# Get all articles in category from Wikipedia

Tags: export, wikipedia, article

I'm trying to get a .csv of all living people listed on wikipedia, preferably with biographic columns for birth date, nationality, etc. I've tried the [Special Export page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3AExport) to export the records as an .xml but it seems there are too many records for a proper export (there are about 800,000 living people in Wikipedia). I also tried [Petscan](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?psid=19820) but this only generates a .csv with the titles of the Wikipedia pages with no actual content.

What would be the best way to go about exporting this data? I'm ok with exporting as an .xml file and converting this to a .csv manually.